# Using horizontalscrollview in a fragment (swipe through tabs)

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe, horizontalscrollview

I am working on this project where I have a group of fragments in between I scroll, swipe.

I wanted to add a `HorizontalScrollView`. I did but I figured that my swiping through fragments and and this `HorizontalScrollView` can't get along well, one works sometimes, and the other other times.

I want my `HorizontalScrollView` to work at all times whenever I am on it swiping.

What I want to do is something like this, with an extra of tabs above:

[image]

So... here is my layout of the fragment I am trying to put the `HorizontalScrollView` in to:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:accordion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto/com.nana.boo"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.nana.boo.source.SomeCustomView
        android:id="@+id/accordion_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        accordion:header_layout_fold_button_id="@id/foldButton"
        accordion:header_layout_id="@layout/accordion_header"
        accordion:header_layout_label_id="@id/foldText"
        accordion:section_bottom="@layout/accordion_footer"
        accordion:section_container="@layout/accordion_section"
        accordion:section_container_parent="@id/section_content"
        accordion:section_headers="@array/accordion_sections"
        accordion:section_visibility="@array/accordion_visibility"
        android:background="#fff5f5f5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/siparisSum"
                style="@style/SummaryButtons"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="Item 1" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nana"
                style="@style/SummaryButtons"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="Item 1" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mama"
                style="@style/SummaryButtons"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="Item 1" />

        </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/example_get_by_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Item 4" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </com.nana.boo.source.SomeCustomView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As I have said this works alone pretty well. But this is a fragment, which I swipe through, How can I intercept this swipe ability and put the `HorizontalScrollView` ahead?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with a [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) to achieve it.

Comment: won't that also get mixed with swipe ability?